# Backspace Character In output

Tags: discussion, output

If a program outputs some string. And then deletes part of the string with the backspace character (in java "\b"). And procedes to print the rest to spec. Would this be considered a violation?

Comment: To summarize my answer to the other question: Control characters like BS are allowed in ASCII art challenges as long as the challenge doesn't specify a specific byte stream, but not in others.

Comment: Thanks! My Bad I showed have looked deeper for a response to this. @Dennis